# How can I compare trainable_weights from a model to know if it is learning anything?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using Tensorflow 2.x and Python 3.7.

My model doesn't improve its loss and accuracy and I'm trying to guess what it is happening.

I have found this article "[How to unit test machine learning code](https://medium.com/@keeper6928/how-to-unit-test-machine-learning-code-57cf6fd81765)" with the following code:

```
def test_convnet():
  image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 100, 100, 3)
  model = Model(image)
  sess = tf.Session()
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  before = sess.run(tf.trainable_variables())
  _ = sess.run(model.train, feed_dict={
               image: np.ones((1, 100, 100, 3)),
               })
  after = sess.run(tf.trainable_variables())
  for b, a, n in zip(before, after):
      # Make sure something changed.
      assert (b != a).any()
```

This is my CNN:

```
import os
import glob

from PIL import Image

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from typing import Tuple

# Create the function that get the embeddings. In this case, it is a CNN.
def get_embedding_function(img_shape):
    inputs = Input(img_shape)

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_1')(inputs)
    #conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool1')(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_1')(pool1)
    #conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_1')(pool2)
    #conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_2')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_1')(pool3)
    #conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_2')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool4')(conv4)

    outputs = Flatten(data_format='channels_last')(pool4)
    print("Pool 4 shape: ", pool4.shape)
    print("Outputs shape: ", outputs.shape)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    return model
```

And here is the training loop:

```
# Load images from disk.
train_dataset = load_images(main_dir, train_classes, (no_of_classes, num_examples, img_height, img_width))

# Input image shape for embeddings function.
input_img_shape = (img_height, img_width, channels)
# Get the embeddings function
emb_function = get_embedding_function(input_img_shape)
# Get the optimizer as Stochastic Gradient Descend.
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1, momentum=0.9)

before = emb_function.trainable_variables

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # 2.1. Since we perform episodic training.
    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        # Select 60 classes RANDOMLY
        episodic_classes = np.random.permutation(no_of_classes)[:num_way]

        support = np.zeros([num_way, num_shot, img_height, img_width], dtype=np.float32)
        query = np.zeros([num_way, num_query, img_height, img_width], dtype=np.float32)

        # 2.2. Randomly sample n number of data points per each class from our dataset, D, and prepare our
        # support set, S.
        for index, class_ in enumerate(episodic_classes):
            selected = np.random.permutation(num_examples)[:num_shot + num_query]
            support[index] = train_dataset[class_, selected[:num_shot]]

            # 3. Similarly, we select n number of data points and prepare our query set, Q. (5 query points per class).
            query[index] = train_dataset[class_, selected[num_shot:]]

        # Add a new dimension at the end of the arrays to store the channels.
        support_set = np.expand_dims(support, axis=-1)
        query_set = np.expand_dims(query, axis=-1)

        # Create an array of arrays [[0, ..., 0], [1, ..., 1], ..., [num_way, ..., num_way]]
        # Each [0, ..., 0], [1, ..., 1], etc. has num_query elements.
        labels = np.tile(np.arange(num_way)[:, np.newaxis], (1, num_query)).astype(np.uint8)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # 4. We learn the embeddings of the data points in our support set using our embedding function.
            support_set_embeddings = \
                emb_function(tf.reshape(support_set, (num_way * num_shot, img_height, img_width, channels)))

            # Convert the label to one hot.
            # Convert labels, [[0, ..., 0], [1, ..., 1], ...], into [[1.0, 0., ..., 0.], [0., 1.0, ...], ...]
            y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_way)

            # 5. Once we have the embeddings for each data point, we compute the prototype of each class by taking the
            # mean.
            # embeddings of the data points under each class.
            class_prototype = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(support_set_embeddings,
                                                        (num_way, num_shot, support_set_embeddings.shape[-1])), axis=1)

            # 6. Similarly, we learn the query set embeddings.
            query_set_embeddings = \
                emb_function(np.reshape(query_set, (num_way * num_query, img_height, img_width, channels)))

            # 7. We calculate the Euclidean distance, d, between query set embeddings and the class prototype.
            distance = euclidean_distance(class_prototype, query_set_embeddings)

            # 8. We predict the probability of the class of a query set by applying softmax over the distance d.
            predicted_probability = tf.reshape(tf.nn.softmax(-distance), (num_way, num_query, -1))

            # 9. We compute the loss as a negative log probability.
            loss = -tf.math.log(
                tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(y_one_hot, predicted_probability), axis=-1), [-1])))

            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(predicted_probability, axis=-1), labels), tf.float32))

            grad = tape.gradient([loss], emb_function.trainable_weights)
            opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, emb_function.trainable_weights))

            after = emb_function.trainable_variables

            for b, a in zip(before, after):
                assert (b != a).any()

            if (episode + 1) % 10 == 0:
                print('Epoch {} : Episode {} : Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}'.format(epoch + 1, episode + 1, loss, accuracy))
```

To make you easier to find how I have migrated the article's code `test_convnet()`, I put it here:

```
before = emb_function.trainable_weights

            # Code omitted for brevity...
            grad = tape.gradient([loss], emb_function.trainable_weights)
            opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, emb_function.trainable_weights))

            after = emb_function.trainable_weights

            for b, a in zip(before, after):
                assert (b != a).any()
```

My problem is with the code `assert (b != a).any()`, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'any'
```

I have also tried `assert (b.any() != a.any())` with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'ResourceVariable' object has no attribute 'any'
```

`before` and `after` are `List`s, so I've been searching for how to compare it, but there are a lot of problems if the lists aren't ordered.

How can I know if the model has been trained?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a way to compare it.

`before` and `after` are my model's `trainable_weights`. They are Python Lists.

Their elements are  `<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>`. If I print one of these elements I get the following:

```
<tf.Variable 'conv1_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 64) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[ ... ]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Each of these `ResourceVariable` have a Numpy array, which elements are `float32`.

Two compare any of these two `ResourceVariable` I have done this:

```
def assert_equals(list1, list2):

    result = True

    for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
        if a.numpy().all() == b.numpy().all():
            result = False
            break

    return result
```